# Is there any interpretation on the Hodge star operator being invariant under holomorphic change of coordinates?

Tags: differential-forms

In this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator), the following is said:

> The Hodge star has the remarkable property that it is invariant under **holomorphic changes of coordinate.**

So, I know three interpretation of holomorphic change of coordinates:

1. Conformality being preserved
2. Infinitesimal shape mapped to similar infinitesimal shape (or , inifinitesimal circle centered get sent to a circle)
3. Squares get sent to squares

Now, could I use this interpretation to understand the Hodge star, or, would there be some other way?

Comment: The example given there uses the standard Hermitian metric on $\mathbb{C}$. The standard Euclidean product $g$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the real part of this Hermitian metric.

The Cauchy-Riemann equations for any $f$ mapping $\mathbb{C}$ into itself imply that the Euclidean metric is transforms conformally invariant $f^*g=\lambda g$ for some positive function (actually, the determinant of real Jacobian of the map $f$).
The tricky part is whether the Hodge star is a conformal invariant. This is interesting for physics, (Maxwell eqns in terms of $*$ are then conformally invariant).

Comment: For the conformal invariance you might want to check [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3635174/hodge-star-is-conformally-invariant-on-lambdan-2v-for-n-even), and recall that for complex manifolds dimension is even. Note however that $\star$ is invariant only on the middle dimension forms.

Comment: Adding this all together, I suspect that the Hodge star is invariant under holomorphic transformations **only** for the half-dimension forms (as in Wikipedia, for 1-forms on the real 2-dimensional $\mathbb{C}$.)